# Programmatically iterate over chunks in a text diff

Tags: python, diff, patch

I'm programming in python, and I'm wondering if there is an easy way to iterate over (and parse) the individual chunks of a text diff, as outputted by the `diff` utility.

Pseudo python code:

```
textdiff = diff('file1', 'file2') # Pretend this is a way of producing a diff
for chunk in textdiff:
    print('These lines are deleted: ', chunk.deletions)
    ... # And do some other interesting stuff with the extracted contents of the chunk.
```

Comment: Why not use [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)?

Comment: "Easy" depends on the actual task, can you give an example? And you'll most likely need the `re` module.

Comment: Diff chunks start lines start and finish with @@ so it's not a complicated task to begin with. Are you looking for a function already doing that ?

Comment: @DisplayName it seems difflib can produce diffs, but not interact with them. It seems you need to parse the result again before you can use it. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jasper updated the example code a bit, but the gist is that the contents of the chunks must be extracted from the diff

Comment: @AlexGarcia Maybe that's the way to go. But it'd be convenient if there is a function that parses it, or even better, a function that produces a diff in terms of python object (instead of text).

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

Use the `SequenceMatcher` class from the `difflib` library. This is the class used by the `difflib` functions. Using this class directly will allow you to iterate over the "chunks" of the diff without having to parse the results of any of the diff functions.

### Sample Solution

Here is an example script to illustrate the idea:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Iterate over the chunks of a diff between two files."""

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def diff(a, b):
    """Iterate over the chunks of a diff between two files.
    
    Examples:

    Replace a single line:

    >>> for chunk in diff(["1\\n"], ["2\\n"]):
    ...     print(chunk)
    {'tag': 'replace', 'i1': 0, 'i2': 1, 'j1': 0, 'j2': 1, 'a': ['1\\n'], 'b': ['2\\n']}

    Delete a single line:

    >>> for chunk in diff(["1\\n"], []):
    ...     print(chunk)
    {'tag': 'delete', 'i1': 0, 'i2': 1, 'j1': 0, 'j2': 0, 'a': ['1\\n'], 'b': []}

    Insert a single line:

    >>> for chunk in diff([], ["2\\n"]):
    ...     print(chunk)
    {'tag': 'insert', 'i1': 0, 'i2': 0, 'j1': 0, 'j2': 1, 'a': [], 'b': ['2\\n']}
    """

    # Iterate over the groups of opcodes and yield the chunks as dicts
    for group in SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b).get_grouped_opcodes(n=0):
        for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in group:
            if tag in ('replace', 'delete', 'insert'):
                patch = {
                    "tag": tag,
                    "i1": i1,
                    "i2": i2,
                    "j1": j1,
                    "j2": j2,
                    "a": a[i1:i2],
                    "b": b[j1:j2],
                }
                yield patch

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    # Get the contents of the first file as a list of lines
    a = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()

    # Get the contents of the second file as a list of lines
    b = open(sys.argv[2]).readlines()

    # Iterate over the chunks of the diff and print them
    for chunk in diff(a, b):
        print(chunk)
```

### Additional Explanation

Here is the source code for the `difflib` library https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/difflib.py

Looking through the `difflib` source code, it appears that its diff functions rely on the `SequenceMatcher` class. This class provides methods which iterate over the "chunks" of the diff.

For example, consider the `unified_diff` function, found here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12a30bc1aa0586308bf3fe12c915bcc5e54a032f/Lib/difflib.py#L1095-L1161)

Here is the implementation of `unified_diff`:

```py
def unified_diff(a, b, fromfile='', tofile='', fromfiledate='',
                 tofiledate='', n=3, lineterm='\n'):

    _check_types(a, b, fromfile, tofile, fromfiledate, tofiledate, lineterm)
    started = False
    for group in SequenceMatcher(None,a,b).get_grouped_opcodes(n):
        if not started:
            started = True
            fromdate = '\t{}'.format(fromfiledate) if fromfiledate else ''
            todate = '\t{}'.format(tofiledate) if tofiledate else ''
            yield '--- {}{}{}'.format(fromfile, fromdate, lineterm)
            yield '+++ {}{}{}'.format(tofile, todate, lineterm)

        first, last = group[0], group[-1]
        file1_range = _format_range_unified(first[1], last[2])
        file2_range = _format_range_unified(first[3], last[4])
        yield '@@ -{} +{} @@{}'.format(file1_range, file2_range, lineterm)

        for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in group:
            if tag == 'equal':
                for line in a[i1:i2]:
                    yield ' ' + line
                continue
            if tag in {'replace', 'delete'}:
                for line in a[i1:i2]:
                    yield '-' + line
            if tag in {'replace', 'insert'}:
                for line in b[j1:j2]:
                    yield '+' + line
```

As you can see, it's the `get_grouped_opcodes` method of the `SequenceMatcher` class which iterates over the chunks of the diff.

More precisely, the `get_grouped_opcodes` method returns a generator which iterates over lists of tuples which identify matching chunks between the two files. Each tuple has the following format:

`(tag, i1, i2, j1, j2)`

where `tag` identifies the relationship between the two matching blocks of code (`tag` is one of `replace`, `delete`, `insert`, or `equal`), `i1` and `i2` are indices which identify a block of code in file `a`, and `j1` and `j2` are indices which identify the corresponding block of code in file `b`.

The `unified_diff` function produces output in unidiff format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format), but we can tweak this function to do something else instead.